# My iPad is completely drained for almost 3 months

Tags: ios, apple-id, charger

I left my iPad 2 unused for almost 3 months because I don't have a charger and no one wanted to use it so it's stucked and unused. When I bought a new charger for my iPad and charged it, the battery sign shown up but no other movement happens. Is my iPad broken?

Comment: How long did you charge it for?

Comment: almost 30 mins.

Comment: Try charging for a few hours, and then see if you can turn on the iPad.

Comment: Are you using a 12watt iPad charger or a 5watt phone charger?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your iPad charging for at least some hours and let's see if the battery can "wake up". Some of my old cellphones' battery only "wake up" after like one day of charging. Hope everything is alright, or you would need to have the battery replaced.